# Upload files to azure blob with async using python get stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing, upload, azure-blob-storage

I have a directory of images which I want to upload to azure blob.
I use the following python code:

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    def upload_file_to_blob(file_path, dest):
         file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
         blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name, os.path.join(dest, file_name))
         with open(file_path, "rb") as data:        
             blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
      
    with Pool(processes=10) as pool:
         for file_ind, file_path in enumerate(file_list):
             pool.apply_async(upload_file_to_blob, args=(file_path, file_dest))
         pool.close()
         pool.join()
    print(f"done")
```

It seems that all of the files were indeed uploaded, but the program is stuck at finish and the final print is not printed to the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As per doco in https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html - "If the optional argument timeout is None (the default), the method blocks until the process whose join() method is called terminates."  May be try with a timeout to debug further?

Comment: @Anand Pool.join() does not take any arguments. I guess you are refering to Process.join() which does

Comment: why using multiprocessing in first place for an I/O constrained operation, for me it seems more like a async operation?

Comment: Which operation would you use? Multithread? @ZiurOlpa

Comment: Azure does have an aioBlobClient package specifically for this use, in linux that may be the best choice.

however, for me, in windows it had so many bugs it was better to use the normal library with asyincio.to_thread() function for the operation that sends the blob.

Is not a optimal solution (till the guys of microsoft solve their bugs) so make sure to measure the performance difference for your use case as it may depend on the size and number of files that this solution is worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below code I am able to Upload multiple files from the folder to Azure Blob storage.

```py
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

# Replace these placeholders with your Azure Blob Storage connection information
connection_string = ""
container_name = " "
local_file_path = " "  # Replace with your local file path
file_dest = "your_destination_folder"

def upload_file_to_blob(file_path, dest):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name, os.path.join(dest, file_name))
    with open(file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=1) as pool:  # Using 1 process for a single file
        result = pool.apply_async(upload_file_to_blob, args=(local_file_path, file_dest))
        result.get()  # Wait for the task to complete

    print("done")
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

[image]
**Code:**

```py
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

# Replace these placeholders with your Azure Blob Storage connection information
connection_string = ""
container_name = " "
local_file_paths = ["C:/Users/Newfolder13.zip", "C:/Users/DotNet6.zip"]  # Put the file paths in a list
file_dest = "your_destination_folder"

def upload_file_to_blob(file_path, dest):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name, os.path.join(dest, file_name))
    with open(file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=10) as pool:  # Use 10 processes for parallel uploads
        for file_path in local_file_paths:
            pool.apply_async(upload_file_to_blob, args=(file_path, file_dest))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()  # Wait for all processes to complete

    print("done")
```

- with `processes=10`

[image]

[image]

- For more details refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227677/upload-multiple-files-from-folder-to-azure-blob-storage-using-azure-storage-sdk#:%7E:text=You%20could%20potentially%20achieve%20better%20upload%20performance%20by,Thread%20import%20os%20%23%20Uploads%20a%20single%20blob.).

Comment: Won't using result.get() in a loop (as I mentioned, the point is to upload multiple files in parallel) destroy the point of parallel?

Comment: @gozi updated please check

Comment: @Sampath why using muiltiprocessing and not the aioBlobClient?